# Not sure what is causing my issue but when i change my code Visual Studio doesn't see or compile the changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

Okay so here it goes. We have been working on our site which is written in asp.net, when recently our .cs files have been acting in a very particular way. When ever we go to change or add code to the.cs files everything appears to be fine until we go to test the code that we have written and debug it. When we go to debug the code is read as if the original unaltered file is there. Values that have been changed aren't. New variables don't exist in context and are never read. Old variables that were deleted still pass there value to other variables that should be grabbing there value from somewhere else. In short my first words were that our code is possessed.

Steps we have taking so far with no result:
 We have tried deleting/excluding our .dll files. Didn't fix it.
 We have tried deleting the temporary folder in the windows directory. Didn't fix it.
 We have tried working on the code offline separated from sourcesafe. Didn't fix it.

If anyone has any input as to why this is happening that would be great. Unfortunately i am unable to share any code on this one.

Updated info based on comments:

we are using asp.net 3.5.
 Not sure if the issue came after deploy or not.
 And we have figured out this is happened based on using watches and break points and seeing value and variables either not change when a simple this = this is assigned or seeing the cursor jump over things that are not in a selection statement where that kind of behavior would happen. Have also seen a const variable that originally equal lets say 100, that we decided to have it instead equal lets say 20. so the const's declaration was changed so it equaled 20 not 100. but when we would run the debug it would still show that it was equal to 100 even though no where in the code did should it equal 100 at any point.
In short we figured out we had this weird issue by trying to test our code using our debugging tools and noticing that things that were suppose to be different on the site weren't changing.

More Updated news:

I was recently informed that there were a ton more .dll's and .pdb's then what i originally thought. was also informed not to delete them but exclude them. so i did what was asked and wow the error list that poured through was tremendous. I believe i have narrowed down where things are going cattiwompas. Will update if things get better.

Comment: Very Important:  *How* are you determining that these things you described in the first paragraph are happening as you say they are?  Be specific.

Comment: Also, ASP.NET: what sub-framework, how is it hosted? Did the problems start after a 'deploy' ?

Comment: Is it a web site (File->New Web Site), or Web Application Project (File->New Project)?

Comment: its a web application project

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting your .pdb files and recompiling.

Comment: This was my suspicion too.

Comment: Yea when i first looked into the issue a lot of what i read and came across suggested deleting the .ddl's and .pdb's so that was my first step. i also saw suggestions for deleting the temp file for the project and tried that as well. still having the issue though so not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting your site's folder under:

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Once you do this the cache will be clear and site recompiled.

Answer (score 0):

Re-starting the application pool clears the cache and releases objects from memory. Give it a go.

Comment: unfortunately still didn't fix it

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in the Configuration Manager that all your projects are selected to be built?

Comment: yup it's there and checked for build. still acting possessed

Answer (score 0):

So from what i have been told is the weird thing that was occurring was happening because it was being opened as a website and not as a solution.